# What is the GPS Hotfix Feature?

Tags: gps

I'm finding that some GPSs (e.g. Garmin nüvi 2300) have a "HotFix" feature that causes satellite connections to be made more quickly.

How does this feature work? Is it internet/WiFi-based, is it similar to WAAS, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://voyager8.blogspot.com/2009/08/garmin-hotfix-technology-powered-by-rx.html

Apparently, the GPS predicts the future positions of satellites.